# Click handler taking a very long time

Tags: javascript, performance

I am going through The Odin Project Etch-a-Sketch and I'm having difficulty with the click handler taking a long time. I'm hoping you can decipher what I have and tell me what I've done incorrectly.

Here's what I receive when clicking the size buttons:

- 16 x 16: Populates the grid - `[Violation] 'click' handler took 276ms`
- 32 x 32: Populates the grid - `[Violation] 'click' handler took 25246ms`
- 64 x 64: Does not populate the grid - No violation, seem hung, page unresponsive

I tried removing the styles if that was hanging up the clicker, no effect.
I removed the `sizeSelected` function but that had no effect.

```
const container = document.getElementById('container');
let size;
let numSize;

sizeSelected();
function sizeSelected () {
  buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    buttons.forEach (button => {
      button.addEventListener ('click', () => {
        size = (button.id);
        numSize = parseInt(size);
        makeGrid();
        // console.log(numSize);
        // console.log(typeof(numSize));
        })
      })
  }


function makeGrid() {
  for(let i = 0; i < numSize; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('grid-item');
    for(let j = 0; j < numSize; j++) {
      let cell = document.createElement('grid-item');
      cell.style.minWidth = "25px";
      cell.style.minHeight = "25px";
      cell.style.background = "yellow";
      cell.style.display = "inline-block";
      cell.innerText = (".");
      cell.style.border = ".5px solid #000000";
      row.appendChild(cell);
      hoverColor();
    }
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(row);
  }
}

function hoverColor (){
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('grid-item');
  items.forEach (item => {
    item.addEventListener ('mouseover', () => {
      item.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    })
  })
}
```

```
:root {
    --grid-cols: 1;
    --grid-rows: 1;
}

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#selection-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

#button-container {
    display: grid;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: The `hoverColor()` function should not be called inside the inner loop in `makeGrid()`. It should be called just once at the end of `makeGrid()`.

Comment: Do not put the HTML in a comment! [Edit] the question.

Comment: Did you really want to have "grid-item" as the ROW and "grid-item" as the column?

Comment: When you call `hoverColor()` where you're currently calling it, you're adding many, many redundant event handlers, all of which will be called upon "click" events.

Comment: change your code from `hoverColor(); }` to `} hoverColor();` so the call is outside the loop.

Comment: And you can just use CSS to set the hover.... you do not need JavaScript at all for that.

Comment: ... sorry I meant "mouseover" events, which is **much** worse.